# Streaming Mp3 File in Android with Media Player

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mp3, media-player

My application works on Android 10 but when I tried my app on Android 5 it's not working.

The mp3 URL starts with "https". When I change the URL to "http" it worked successfully on Android 5.

Which is better for my app, "http" or "https"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is when i tried to stream mp3 file on my app it didn't worked in android 5 because the url link was staring with https, when i changed the url to http it worked successfully. So which url better to use http or https

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is more secure than HTTP. You should use it. In the higher version of Android system, HTTP will not be executed by default because it is not secure.
HTTPS cannot run on Android 5 is a very strange thing, you may have to find out why.

Comment: Thanks bro for your answer, i will try to find out why it's not working in Android 5